# #define statement explained

Tags: c

gcc 4.4.1

I am maintaining someone's code and I have come across something that I don't understand.

```
#define RES_API(name, func) name##_##func
```

Can anyone explain?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `##` operator concatenates two tokens. In your case, `name` is appended with an underscore, and that is appended with `func`.

So `RES_API(aName, aFunc)` results in `aName_aFunc`.

By itself, it seems rather annoying. I could see a use when mixing C and C++ code, as C libraries tend to prefix their functions, while C++ libraries would place them in a namespace.

Given an alternate definition, such as:

```
#define RES_API(name, func) name##::##func
```

You suddenly have a generic way to switch between a C interface, or C++.

Comment: Do you really need the token pasting operators in the C++ code?  I would expect the compiler to object that '::' is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 6):

The `##` is a concatenation operator.  Using `RES_API(name1, func1)` in your code would be replaced with `name1_func1`.  More information [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Answer (score 4):

I know you've already got your answer, but there is some great info on the C-FAQ which explains allot of the [C Preprocessor magic](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=cpp).

Comment: Thanks that was a great link. There was some other stuff in there that I needed for some else like doing the varargs functions. Great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `OBJ_DoSomething`, with this macro you can do `RES_API(OBJ, DoSomething)`.  Personally I think its silly.

Comment: A huge amount of the preprocessor stuff is 'silly', until you suddenly find a reason why you can't do without it :)